How do we update a table column which is list type based on list indices range
How do we update a table column which is list type based on list indices range
sample table
tab:([] date:2024.01.01+til 30;sym:30?`appl`msgt`googl;volume:30#(enlist 0.5+300?til 100));
Lets just work with row1 in current example so its easier
exec first volume from tab where i=0    //300 

Now, we want to query and update the table tab such that user passes start index and end index, take that and update the volume from tab to zero 0 for that index range.
We have 300 values in volume column for first row as eg. , say user passes start:100;end:200, so here we need to make the index 100 to 200 as zero in volume column where its is first row or any row given.
I tried to solve it by indexing a list but it works for single  index but not works for a range of index in update statement

Using . amend
q){[start;end] .[tab;(::;`volume;start+til end-start);:;0f]}[100;200]

This will set indexes 100 to 200 as 0f in every volume row.

Thank you Cathal for your solution, it helped a lot.

How do we copy index value 250 to 50 index specifically?

.[tab;(::;`volume;50);:;.[tab;(::;`volume;250)]]

thank you for your quick reply, one more qq, how do we use this in update statement? It gives me error when i tried to use it in   update volume:{  }'[`volume] from tab

Does it need to be in an update statement?

so basically there is a table where one column has list say volume, sometime it has value and sometime it does not have a value, if in case if did not have values the code breaks with error. we want to have a behavior such a way that if its having nothing then return as it is else process it for each row of table.  so i have came up something like update volume:{$[count x;1b;x]}'[volume] from res, instead of 1b we will do the data processing

Maybe it's worth raising a separate question with some sample input and expected output. It's difficult to know what's required without seeing the shape and meta of the table.

sure, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78899956/how-to-use-amend-in-update-statement
