how to use amend in update statement
We have a table tab
tab:update volume:0n from ([] date:2024.01.01+til 10;sym:10?`appl`msgt`googl;volume:10#(enlist 0.5+300?til 100)) where i in (1;5;8);


We want to update the column volume such a way that, copy bucket value of index 299 to 200 and make zero buckets 201 to 299.
This we can do using amend like this, but amend throws type error when volume is empty/null.
In this behavior we want to not throw error but return empty/null as it is and process only when there is something in volume column.
//original value
first exec volume from select from tab where i=0


//updated expected values, works where volume is not null else gives type error
first exec volume from {[start;end;tab] tt:.[tab;(::;`volume;200);:;.[tab;(::;`volume;299)]]; .[tt;(::;`volume;start+til end-start);:;0f]}[201;299;select from tab where i=0]


But this gives type error where volume is null when we pass the whole table
first exec volume from {[start;end;tab] tt:.[tab;(::;`volume;200);:;.[tab;(::;`volume;299)]]; .[tt;(::;`volume;start+til end-start);:;0f]}[201;299;select from tab]

What's the best way we can check if volume is null then return null/empty do anything else do the processing
something like this
update volume:{ $[count x;"do processing here using amend"; x] }'[volume] from tab


Switching start & end variables for y & z respectively.
q)update volume:{$[1=count x;x;@[;y+til z-y;:;0f]@[x;200;:;x 299]]}'[volume;201;299]from tab

@ amend is sufficient here as the lambda is operating over each volume row and so there is no need to index at depth.

q)update volume:{@[;y+til z-y;:;0f]@[x;200;:;x 299]}'[volume;201;299]from tab where not 1=count each volume  If not operating on some then nice to filter out in where
